# Trimming text strings in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in a SQL Server 2008 database. This table has a nvarchar(256) column called 'Name'. Unfortunately, the values in this field have extra spaces included. For instance the name 'Bill' is actually stored as 'Bill                       ' in the table.

I want to update all of the records in this table to remove the extra spaces. However, I was surprised to learn that SQL does not have a TRIM function.

How do I update all of the records at once to remove the extra spaces?

Thank you!

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You do have an [`RTRIM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx) and an [`LTRIM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx) function. You can combine them to get the trim function you want.

```
UPDATE Table
SET Name = RTRIM(LTRIM(Name))
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use the RTrim function to trim all whitespace from the right. Use LTrim to trim all whitespace from the left. For example

```
UPDATE Table SET Name = RTrim(Name)
```

Or for both left and right trim

```
UPDATE Table SET Name = LTrim(RTrim(Name))
```

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one, because `LTRIM(RTRIM(Name))` is probably more efficient than `RTRIM(LTRIM(Name))`.

Comment: Well, it depends on the internal implementation language. If it is C/C++, then LTRIM has to shift the string characters to the left, whereas RTRIM just writes the terminating '\0' at the right position. So, LTRIM after RTRIM needs to shift less characters. Of course, it does not matter in the big picture, but still this is more efficient and the cost of swapping LTRIM and RTRIM is absolutely 0.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server does not have a TRIM function, but rather it has two.  One each for specifically trimming spaces from the "front" of a string ([LTRIM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177827.aspx)) and one for trimming spaces from the "end" of a string ([RTRIM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx)).

Something like the following will update every record in your table, trimming all extraneous space (either at the front or the end) of a varchar/nvarchar field:

```
UPDATE 
   [YourTableName]
SET
   [YourFieldName] = LTRIM(RTRIM([YourFieldName]))
```

(Strangely, SSIS (Sql Server Integration Services) *does* have a single [TRIM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139947.aspx) function!)

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this for a Trim function that takes into account all white-space characters defined by the Unicode Standard (LTRIM and RTRIM do not even trim new-line characters!):

```html
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.IsWhiteSpace', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.IsWhiteSpace;
GO

-- Determines whether a single character is white-space or not (according to the UNICODE standard).
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsWhiteSpace(@c NCHAR(1)) RETURNS BIT
BEGIN
 IF (@c IS NULL) RETURN NULL;
 DECLARE @WHITESPACE NCHAR(31);
 SELECT @WHITESPACE = ' ' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + NCHAR(9) + NCHAR(11) + NCHAR(12) + NCHAR(133) + NCHAR(160) + NCHAR(5760) + NCHAR(8192) + NCHAR(8193) + NCHAR(8194) + NCHAR(8195) + NCHAR(8196) + NCHAR(8197) + NCHAR(8198) + NCHAR(8199) + NCHAR(8200) + NCHAR(8201) + NCHAR(8202) + NCHAR(8232) + NCHAR(8233) + NCHAR(8239) + NCHAR(8287) + NCHAR(12288) + NCHAR(6158) + NCHAR(8203) + NCHAR(8204) + NCHAR(8205) + NCHAR(8288) + NCHAR(65279);
 IF (CHARINDEX(@c, @WHITESPACE) = 0) RETURN 0;
 RETURN 1;
END
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Trim', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.Trim;
GO

-- Removes all leading and tailing white-space characters. NULL is converted to an empty string.
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Trim(@TEXT NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
 -- Check tiny strings (NULL, 0 or 1 chars)
 IF @TEXT IS NULL RETURN N'';
 DECLARE @TEXTLENGTH INT = LEN(@TEXT);
 IF @TEXTLENGTH < 2 BEGIN
  IF (@TEXTLENGTH = 0) RETURN @TEXT;
  IF (dbo.IsWhiteSpace(SUBSTRING(@TEXT, 1, 1)) = 1) RETURN '';
  RETURN @TEXT;
 END
 -- Check whether we have to LTRIM/RTRIM
 DECLARE @SKIPSTART INT;
 SELECT @SKIPSTART = dbo.IsWhiteSpace(SUBSTRING(@TEXT, 1, 1));
 DECLARE @SKIPEND INT;
 SELECT @SKIPEND = dbo.IsWhiteSpace(SUBSTRING(@TEXT, @TEXTLENGTH, 1));
 DECLARE @INDEX INT;
 IF (@SKIPSTART = 1) BEGIN
  IF (@SKIPEND = 1) BEGIN
   -- FULLTRIM
   -- Determine start white-space length
   SELECT @INDEX = 2;
   WHILE (@INDEX < @TEXTLENGTH) BEGIN -- Hint: The last character is already checked
    -- Stop loop if no white-space
    IF (dbo.IsWhiteSpace(SUBSTRING(@TEXT, @INDEX, 1)) = 0) BREAK;
    -- Otherwise assign index as @SKIPSTART
    SELECT @SKIPSTART = @INDEX;
    -- Increase character index
    SELECT @INDEX = (@INDEX + 1);
   END
   -- Return '' if the whole string is white-space
   IF (@SKIPSTART = (@TEXTLENGTH - 1)) RETURN ''; 
   -- Determine end white-space length
   SELECT @INDEX = (@TEXTLENGTH - 1);
   WHILE (@INDEX > 1) BEGIN 
    -- Stop loop if no white-space
    IF (dbo.IsWhiteSpace(SUBSTRING(@TEXT, @INDEX, 1)) = 0) BREAK;
    -- Otherwise increase @SKIPEND
    SELECT @SKIPEND = (@SKIPEND + 1);
    -- Decrease character index
    SELECT @INDEX = (@INDEX - 1);
   END
   -- Return trimmed string
   RETURN SUBSTRING(@TEXT, @SKIPSTART + 1, @TEXTLENGTH - @SKIPSTART - @SKIPEND);
  END 
  -- LTRIM
  -- Determine start white-space length
  SELECT @INDEX = 2;
  WHILE (@INDEX < @TEXTLENGTH) BEGIN -- Hint: The last character is already checked
   -- Stop loop if no white-space
   IF (dbo.IsWhiteSpace(SUBSTRING(@TEXT, @INDEX, 1)) = 0) BREAK;
   -- Otherwise assign index as @SKIPSTART
   SELECT @SKIPSTART = @INDEX;
   -- Increase character index
   SELECT @INDEX = (@INDEX + 1);
  END
  -- Return trimmed string
  RETURN SUBSTRING(@TEXT, @SKIPSTART + 1, @TEXTLENGTH - @SKIPSTART);
 END ELSE BEGIN
  -- RTRIM
  IF (@SKIPEND = 1) BEGIN
   -- Determine end white-space length
   SELECT @INDEX = (@TEXTLENGTH - 1);
   WHILE (@INDEX > 1) BEGIN 
    -- Stop loop if no white-space
    IF (dbo.IsWhiteSpace(SUBSTRING(@TEXT, @INDEX, 1)) = 0) BREAK;
    -- Otherwise increase @SKIPEND
    SELECT @SKIPEND = (@SKIPEND + 1);
    -- Decrease character index
    SELECT @INDEX = (@INDEX - 1);
   END
   -- Return trimmed string
   RETURN SUBSTRING(@TEXT, 1, @TEXTLENGTH - @SKIPEND);
  END 
 END
 -- NO TRIM
 RETURN @TEXT;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I just found a solution which creates a user defined function using LTRIM and RTRIM. It does not handle double spaces in the middle of a string.

The solution is however straight forward:

[User Defined Trim Function](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/09/sql-server-2008-trim-function-user-defined-function/)

Answer (score 0):

No  Answer is true

The true Answer is Edit Column to NVARCHAR and you found Automatically trim Execute but this code 
UPDATE Table
SET Name = RTRIM(LTRIM(Name))
use it only  with Nvarchar if use it with CHAR or NCHAR it will not work

Comment: What do you expect? With CHAR and NCHAR the string has a fixed length. If you trim the last empty 10 characters of a CHAR(30) and assign it to a CHAR(30) again, the string is filled up to 30 characters again, using spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This function trims a string from left and right. Also it removes carriage returns from the string, an action which is not done by the LTRIM and RTRIM

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.TRIM', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.TRIM;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TRIM (@STR NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
    RETURN(LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(@STR ,CHAR(10),''),CHAR(13),''))))
END;
GO
```

Comment: The problem with your function is that it does not trim CRLFs, they are also replaced within the string which is probably unwanted.