# Query Returns Trailing Blank Characters For Each Returned Item

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, substring

I have the following in a SQL select statement.  It's purpose is to query a number of results and have them returned seperated by comma's.

```
SUBSTRING((
        SELECT ', ' + s.jaopr
        FROM jjops s
        WHERE s.jajob = o.jajob
        ORDER BY s.jaseq
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 2, 1000)
```

I am getting the results I need, however the number of characters in each result varies from 2 characters to 5 characters.  So extra spaces are returned in the results.
Example:
`AA  , AAA  , BBBBB, BBBB , CCCCC`

How can I change my substring so that there are not extra spaces when the returned result has less than 5 characters?

I think I understand what a `Substring` is but I don't quite understand what the `XML PATH` does, as I copied this when searching for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the values stored in the database without trailing (and/or leading) spaces?   If so, that question's been answered here:

[Trimming text strings in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487233/trimming-text-strings-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: I found out my database has stored trailing spaces.  This lead me to the solution thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The usual use of the XML Path as you seem to be using it here (try putting something like "value" in the quotes to get a hint at it's real intended use) is to concatenate some result set that would normally be some number of rows, into a single row where all of the results are in a single string.

That being the case, what should happen here is that the substring function should return the entire result of the inner query, from the second character out to a thousand. The effect would be that if you had five rows of results just in the select statement you have above with no XML path at the end of it like so:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

The XML Path command should give you
, A, B, C, D, E

Notice the spaces after the comma's. It seems like you are trying to use the substring to get rid of the first comma, but that won't get rid of the spaces after commas in the middle.

If I'm right about those assumption then perhaps just deleting the space within the quotes around your comma would give you mostly the effect you want.

However, you might check threads like [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d4bc611f-0951-4ed6-9634-c204b2304f92/stuff-and-for-xml-path) for further reading on accepted ways to accomplish this.