# How can I use TRIM function in a SQL query?

Tags: sql

I would like to use the `trim` function but don't really know how it works.

I need to select items in a table and export it on a CSV file.

It's working fine but sometime when I have a specific data (here it's a string), the csv file write it with à CR LF and write at the line after.

I think that a problem with the data in the data base and that there "something" after my data in this specific field.

I have this query:

```
string request = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
```

And I want to try this but I'm not sure.

```
string request = "SELECT * TRIM(TRAILING FROM ") + tableName;
```

Comment: what is the backend here? how to use it will depend **hugely** on what the DB server is; Oracle, Access, SQL Server, PostgreSQL etc will all work differently here... Also: what do you expect this to *do*? I'm not sure it makes sense in the way you're asking, so what do you mean the output to do here?

Comment: Incorrectly tagged as a C# question. Its SQL of some flavour, tell us which and update the tags.

Comment: if your intention here is to trim each column: you would need to write an SQL column that applied TRIM **separately** to each column; frankly, it would be a lot easier to do the trim during the export in the C# code, and leave the SQL alone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trimming text strings in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487233/trimming-text-strings-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: My question was about a project in C# in visual studio 2015 and the data base is Advantage Data base (Sybase Sql).

I would like to export the result of the query in a csv file.

Answer (score 2):

if you are trying in SQL SERVER.

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(COLUMN))
```